# Blank error when executing a macro with a runpython form another runpython

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have an Excel with a macro that calls a python process through runpython API from xlwings. The invocated python process opens another excel file that has got a macro  with a runpython and executes this macro.

Excel 1 Macro:

```
Public Sub macro1()

    Call RunPython("import myModule; myModule.inputProcess();")

End Sub
```

Python code 1:

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
# Performs some task with Excel 1 ...

# Opens excel 2
wb2 = xw.Book(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\' + \
                         "excel2.xlsm")

macro_2 = wb2.macro("macro2")
macro_2()
```

Excel 2 Macro:

```
Public Sub macro2()

    Call RunPython("import myModule2; myModule2.inputProcess2();")

End Sub
```

When It starts to execute the second runpython I get the following blank error message window.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that there is not an invocation stack to manage this kind of recursion with Runpython, and environment variables are lost in the second xlwings.Book.caller() execution. I have just adopted a solution that does not use more than one xlwings.Book.caller() execution...

Comment: I have this same issue, but with only one caller